# display:grid. How to stretch a block to full width

Tags: css, css-grid

I am studying the grid. I want the third block to stretch to its full width. If possible without adding additional classes.

**Is it possible to do it using internal CSS?**

```css
.grid {
  margin: 36px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  
  & > * {
    border: dotted 2px black;
  }
}
.first {
  background-color: #6CD4FF;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.second {
  background-color: #8B8DF9;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.third {
  background-color: #DDFD77;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I want to get the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okRMj.png).

Comment: Why do you say 'without additional classes' ?. There are many ways to solve a problem so here either you make changes in CSS or in HTML to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: Maybe it is not possible only using CSS, you must change HTML structure or add other one additional class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), which won't need you to use media queries, and only using CSS Grid properties.

```
.second + .third {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

or:

```
// A bit more generic
div + .third {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  margin: 36px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  
  & > * {
    border: dotted 2px black;
  }
}
.first {
  background-color: #6CD4FF;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.second {
  background-color: #8B8DF9;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.third {
  background-color: #DDFD77;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.second + .third {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha! For some reason I did not think about it)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution where you can use `nth-child()` selectors:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 36px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}
.grid > * {
    border: dotted 2px black;
  }

.first {
  background-color: #6CD4FF;
}
.second {
  background-color: #8B8DF9;
}
.third {
  background-color: #DDFD77;
}
.grid :nth-child(3):last-child {
  grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. hope will help you.

```css
.grid {
  margin: 36px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  
  & > * {
    border: dotted 2px black;
  }
}
.first {
  background-color: #6CD4FF;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.second {
  background-color: #8B8DF9;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.third {
  background-color: #DDFD77;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="first"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this changes the HTML structure